# Python Logging Module Inconsistent Behaviour

Tags: python, logging

I've seen some very odd behaviour with the logger module. It started with a relatively complex project, but now I've seen it with the following script:

```py
import logging
import os

# Uncomment the following line to remove handlers
# logging.getLogger().handlers = [] 

filePath = os.environ['userprofile']  + r'\Documents\log.txt'
logging.basicConfig(filename=filePath)
logging.debug('Gleep')
logging.shutdown()
```

This should simply write 'Gleep' to the log.txt file to your documents. Currently it is writing the file but not writing anything to it, however, I've inconsistently seen the following behaviour:

1. List item
2. No log file being written at all.
3. Log file created, but nothing written to it.
4. Everything working fine.

The only way I've got it working before is to remove existing handlers (commented out in the example above). 
This is on several machines in different locations.

So...am I doing something grotesquely wrong here? Why is the logging module acting this way?

Comment: Using threading/multiprocessing? Or maybe an IDE with memory like Spyder (or maybe even Jupyter, which I don't use - anything with IPython). In other words, your setup is probably important here

Comment: The above script was just run via Sublime Text.
I'm unsure what the default is supposed to be, but I just noticed that if I add level=logging.DEBUG to the basicConfig then the text is written to the file.
Is this normal?

Comment: I edited my comment a few times. Please see its final incarnation.

Comment: This is just a regular python script running on python27. Logging library is the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to prove/disprove/debug your 'other' situations, but maybe the following can help clarify what is happening in the code from your question:

First, setting `logging.getLogger().handlers = []` should *not* be necessary, since `logging.getLogger()` is the root logger by default and has no handlers.  Here is a fresh Python 3.7 shell:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.getLogger()
<RootLogger root (WARNING)>
>>> logging.getLogger().handlers
[]
```

(Note that in the absence of any handlers, a logger will fall back to [`lastResort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.lastResort), but that should be irrelevant here since you add a handler implicitly via `basicConfig()`.)

Which brings you to `logging.basicConfig(filename=filePath)`: this adds a `FileHandler` handler to the root logger.  It does not touch the level of the root logger, which is **`WARNING` by default**, so your message won't pass the 'level test' and won't be emitted as a result.

```
>>> logging.root.getEffectiveLevel()
30
```

(This uses `.getEffectiveLevel()` rather than just the plain attribute because a logger will walk its hierarchy until it finds a level if its level is `NOTSET`.)

All that is to say: as you currently have it, you are logging from the root logger (level `WARNING`) a message object that has level `DEBUG`, so the message will go nowhere.

---

Comment: This was a case of me not having a good enough grasp on the logging module and the way it functions, particularly when it comes to the logging level combined with new handlers.
In the end I did the following
`watchLogger = logging.getLogger()
watchLogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(path, 'log.txt'))
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt='%(levelname)s : %(asctime)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
watchLogger.addHandler(handler)`

So I'm adding a FileHandler to the StreamHandler that was already present.